# Vim: quickfix encoding on Windows

Tags: vim

Consider the following minimal vimrc file:

```
set nocompatible
set encoding=utf-8

function! MakePython()
    lcd %:p:h
    setlocal errorformat=%+G%.%#
    let &l:makeprg = 'python '. expand('%:p:t')
    silent make!
    echo getqflist()[0].text
endfunction
```

If I start Gvim with this minimal vimrc, then edit a `foo.py` file containing

```
print('Año')
```

and finally run `:!python %` I correctly see `Año` in the console. On the other hand if run `:call MakePython()` I get `A<f1>o`. So my question is how can I get `Año` instead of `A<f1>o` in the quickfix list?

For the record: I'm on Windows using Python 3.4.

*Edit*: The problem seems to be that vim converts an `utf-8` string to `latin1` since `:echo iconv('Año', 'utf-8', 'latin1')` returns `A<f1>o`. I have no idea how to prevent this from happening.

Comment: what is the output `:set encoding?` ?

Comment: @Kent `:set encoding?` where? In the `foo.py` is `utf-8`.

Comment: it checks your vim encoding, nothing to do with your file. You can open vim with an empty buffer to check. Why do you have to convert `utf-8` into `cp1251`?  Your file is utf-8, and your vim is utf-8 too, usually you don't have to do encoding conversion.

Comment: My vim encoding is indeed `utf-8`. I tried converting from `utf-8` into `cp1251` to attempt to fix my problem. However since it did not fix it I posted such problem here.

Comment: What I mean is that without the `iconv(item.text, 'cp1251', 'utf-8')`, `echo getqflist()[0].text` still returns `A<f1>o` instead of `Año`.

Comment: I did a test with your `foo.py` my vim has encoding utf-8 too. After calling your function (without the iconv line), I see `Año` in output. Open qf window, `Año` shows too. I am on linux box. Don't have windows, cannot help further.

Comment: Thanks @Kent for testing.  Yeah,  it's probably a Windows problem.

Comment: VIM on Windows is not a Unicode application, it is ANSI. Windows would perform automatic conversion of the child output to the default 1-byte encoding.

Comment: @Dummy00001 thanks for the explanation. Is there a solution then?

Comment: @petobens try starting the process via the `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c` (it is a Unicode app),  redirecting the output into a temp file, and then reading that file into VIM with the `:cfile` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should've read `quickfix.txt` help more carefully:

> When 'encoding' differs from the locale, the error messages may have a
>   different encoding from what Vim is using.

Since my locale is `latin1` and my encoding `utf-8`, doing:

```
echo iconv(getqflist()[0].text, 'latin1', 'utf-8')
```

fixes the problem.